# Holding current of a thyristor

Tags: current

What is the anode to cathode voltage that corresponds to the holding current?And is the forward conduction current extremely large?I see no limitation besides the forward resistance of the device.

Comment: Why do you even need to know? Keep the current above the holding current and the device will stay on. Don't, and it will turn off.

Comment: Wow.That is new information.

Answer (score 1):

The anode-to-cathode voltage at the holding current is usually around a volt. Of course the holding current is much less than the maximum forward current. Take a typical smallish thristor, the [S6025NRP](http://www.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/switching_thyristors/littelfuse_thyristor_sxx20x_sxx25x_datasheet.pdf.pdf) 25A/600V SCR. Holding current is maximum 50mA. Perhaps not surprisingly, it's similar to the gate trigger current of 35mA maximum.

From the datasheet you can see the variation in holding current vs. temperature, and the on-state voltage, which will be about 0.85V typically at ~50mA.

[image]

Of course it's up to your circuit (such as the load) to limit the forward current. The SCR just acts as a switch.